# Le subjonctif anglais « come » dans le contexte d'une expression : un équivalent français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, temps-grammatical, mode-grammatical

J'étais en train d'écrire un e-mail, et je voulais dire (en anglais) :

> **Come** summer, we will see the results.

Ce qui est équivalent à :

> When summer comes (arrives), we will see the results.

Je cherche un équivalent français du mot « *come* », dans le contexte d'une expression. Étant donné que dans ce cas ci « *come* » est un peu ambigu et comme ma connaissance de la grammaire anglaise n'est pas tout à fait bonne, je ne sais pas exactement comment il fonctionne dans cette phrase-là (soit un verbe au passé composé, soit un verbe au présent mais dans un sens littéraire, etc.).

Franchement la première chose qui m'est venue est :

> L'été **arrivé**, on verra les résultats.

Ici j'utilise **arrivé** comme un participe passé du verbe **arriver**, dans un emploi qui remplace (je crois) :

> **Quand** l'été **arrive**, on verra les résultats.

Mais la phrase « *L'été arrivé, on verra les résultats* » et cette dernière phrase n'ont pas du tout le même sens (à mon avis), parce que *arrivé* indique dans ce contexte que l'été est *déjà* arrivé. Dans l'expression anglaise, le mot « *come* » et utilisé comme un type de *futur*. Est-ce qu'une expression équivalente existe en français ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je trouve bien plus à propos d’employer « venu » plutôt qu’« arrivé » dans ce contexte.

> Nous verrons les résultats l’été venu.

J’aime moins

> L’été venu, nous verrons les résultats.

Ou, tout simplement,

> Nous verrons les résultats à l’été.

Je préfère (sans grande justification) « à l’été » à « en été » dans ce cas précis. « En été » me laisse croire que le bilan pourrait n’avoir lieu qu’à un instant précis de l’été, éventuellement le 20 septembre.

Answer (score 4):

Je trouve [les propositions d'Édouard](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/9239/79) avisées.
Mais je pense que la traduction directe n'est pas impossible non plus.

> Arrive l'été, nous verrons les résultats.

Il y a cependant une part de souhait qui n'est peut-être plus présente dans le subjonctif anglais, l'expression étant maintenant figée.

Comment: On peut préciser que c'est du subjonctif dans ce cas : on pourrait aussi dire "(que) vienne l'été".

Answer (score 1):

> Mais la phrase L'été arrivé, on verra les résultats n'a pas (à mon
>   avis) le même sens du tout de la phrase juste après, parce que arrivé
>   indique dans ce contexte que l'été est déjà arrivé. Dans l'expression
>   anglaise, le mot come et utilisé comme un type de futur. Est-ce qu'une
>   expression équivalente existe en français?

C'est à cet endroit que tu fais erreur. Ton interprétation de la phrase est incorrecte. En effet, ta phrase utilise un temps de verbe au futur (l'autre est simplement un participe) et donc, elle signifie donc exactement:

> On verra les résultats, lorsque l'été sera arrivé.

Cependant, dans un contexte écrit, je n'utiliserais pas la phrase de cette façon (parlé, ça va). Je reformulerais comme cela:

> L'été arrivé, nous verrons les résultats.

Ou plus soutenu:

> Puisse l'été arriver, nous observerons les résultats.

Answer (score -1):

Cet été, nous verrons les résultats.

Comment: Une réponse à la question est cachée dans cette phrase. Ami lecteur, sauras-tu la trouver ? (Indice : ∅)